# Is IE11 really not compatible with getNamedItem() JS function?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to use getNamedItem() function. I can correctly access items using Chrome, Firefox, IE9 and IE10 ... but not when using IE11.

According to this, it seems expected : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_namednodemap_getnameditem.asp

My question is : do we have an equivalent function which could be used in order to work with IE11 ?

Comment: It seems to work in IE11 : [This works](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_namednodemap_getnameditem).

Comment: I would recommend to use a library such as jQuery. A library deals with browser compatibility. If you tell me exactly what you want I can explain  how to do this with jQuery.

Comment: Where does the link say it is expected that IE11 doesn't support it?

Comment: @Matt There are plenty of good reasons to want to program against the browser's interfaces directly without going through jQuery.

Comment: If it works in 9 and 10 there is another issue then, have you validated your markup?

Comment: Where's the code that isn't working?

Comment: @CharlieKilian you're right, however I don't see the reason here. Tell me if you want, for the sake of my ignorance.

Comment: Actually I just realized it works if IE Developer Tool is opened ...

Comment: @Matt : I'm using DOJO framework ... but in this particular scenario I can't use the dijit/registry in order to access my widget because the modification has to be done before the page gets completely parse by DOJO parser.

Answer (score 0):

`getNamedItem()` is supported in IE9+, including IE11.

[**Try this in IE11**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_namednodemap_getnameditem).